# Categories without inductive limits

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory

I came across the notion of inductive limits in C*-algebras, where they exist.
Except for the category of finite sets, what are natural examples of categories which fail to have inductive limits?

Comment: I guess examples like "a non-complete boolean algebra considered as a category" don't count for you either? Obviously, categories with all (co)limits are nice, and one tries to avoid studying categories which are not nice.

Comment: Since your question is tagged functional analysis: The categories of Banach/Fréchet/Hilbert spaces with bounded linear maps or separable $C^\ast$-algebras or general Banach algebras would be natural examples.

Comment: @Zhen: from an analytic perspective completeness is often a bit too much to ask for and I insist that the categories I mentioned are nice and natural. :)

Comment: The category of fields doesn't have coproducts, much less arbitrary direct limits.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

The comments contain the following examples:

- A non-complete Boolean algebra considered as a category;
- The category of Banach/Fréchet/Hilbert spaces with bounded linear maps as morphisms;
- Categories of separable $C^*$-algebras and Banach algebras;
- The category of fields.